# How do I see Deep Sky Objects in my telescope?

Tags: telescope, messier-catalog

I just bought a new telescope. I tried it out, and I even woke up at 3am when the moon set so there was light pollution. I have an 8 inch dobsonian telescope with a focal length of 1200 mm. For some reason, I only see points of light in the sky, except for the moon and Jupiter and the Orion Nebula.

My goal is to complete a messier marathon, but first I need to be able to see the Messier objects. So my question is, what is the best way to look for Deep Sky Objects with my telescope? And how much does light pollution get in the way of looking for them? For reference, I live in the northern United States.

Comment: Does "DSO" mean "Deep Sky Object"? If so, it's probably best not to assume that everyone knows that (I didn't).

Answer (score 1):

To see Deep Sky Objects you'll definitely have to head out of whatever town you're in by at least 5km, but the further the better. Next, you'll have to have a good knowledge of where to look for them or a guide. You should be able to see a fair few once you've done that, especially if you've already seen the Orion Nebula.

Comment: Colder weather might bring clearer skies. Also, try using a lower power eyepiece, if you can.